# Name for a bug that disappears when someone else looks at it

Tags: terminology, debugging

Does anyone know of an existing name for a bug that disappears the moment you call someone over to look at it?  It's a funny phenomenon, but it has happened from time to time that I'm working on a bug that consistently appears, but as soon as I call over a colleague to look at it with me, the buggy behavior stops and doesn't reappear.

This is distinct from any of the other oddball bug names I've found, such as [heisenbug](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html) or [mandelbug](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/mandelbug.html), in that it's definitely there, even when attempting to study it, until it's shown to someone else.

My coworker proposed the name "Calvinbug" for this phenomenon, after Calvin & Hobbes. Thoughts?

And no, I'm not crazy. :)

Comment: every user reported bug ever

Comment: It sounds like a form of heisenbug to me.

Comment: "Heisenbug" doesn't quite fit, because it's a bug that persists when I'm examining it, but only disappears when someone else looks at it.  Seriously, all my team lead has to do sometimes is come over and look at my screen, and the bug is gone.

Comment: I suggest "Ozmodiarbug", since only *you* can see the bug. http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Ozmodiar

Comment: Loch Ness Monster Bug may be appropriate. A few related terms can be found [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

Comment: How about the Warner Brothers Dancing Frog bug? :)

Comment: Ooh.  I'm liking "Dancing Frog Bug" so far.

Comment: @maple_shaft You should phrase that in the form of an answer - I like it better than Snuffleupabugs" (because it's easier to spell), and it will be just as lost on the younger coders!

Comment: To be clear - you might *actually* be crazy, just not about this bug.

Comment: @Keith Thompson is correct: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: Sorry, it's not a Heisenbug... it persists when I attempt to study it, but only disappears when someone else comes over to look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know of no formal term for such a bug, but I would propose the following options:

- **Schrödinger's Bug** - you changed the outcome by measuring it!
- **Snuffleupabugs** -- After Mr. [Snuffleupagus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Snuffleupagus), back when only Big Bird could see it.
  <sup><sub>Unfortunately this one will be lost on the younger coders</sub></sup>

Comment: Unfortunately "[Schroedinbug](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/schroedinbug.html)" is taken, but "Snuffleupabug" is pretty damn good.

Comment: +1 for "Snuffleupabug", exactly what I was thinking.  Make it a "Mister Snuffleupabug" for bonus credit!